# Nested IF Error

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can someone assist me fixing these two arguments:

```
=IF(O18="Ksh",P18,””,IF(O18="USD",P18*U18))
```

Need to next these are two functions, that work when singularly in cell:

```
=IF(O18="Ksh",P18,””)



=IF(O18="USD",P18*U18,"")
```

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the commas in `=IF(O18="Ksh",P18,””,IF(O18="USD",P18*U18))`:

There are three, so that is four arguments.
syntax is; `IF(test_expression, what_to_do_when_True, what_to_do_when_False)`
... so THREE arguments.

Now what did you INTEND with your formula?

`=IF(O18="Ksh",P18,IF(O18="USD",P18*U18,""))` - maybe?

Comment: the third argument of the first IF is a new IF which also needs three arguments, so look at Rajesh's solution which is correct while your second IF is missing the third argument..

Comment: Corrected, is that what was intended - no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

*You need to rewrite your formula like this:*

```
=IF(O18="Ksh",P18,IF(O18="USD",P18*U18,""))
```

Considering this one `=IF(O18="Ksh",P18,””)` you need to replace `””` with `""`,
otherwise you get #NAME error.

Next one has no issue.

- *You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use nested `IF()` functions, here is a fun alternative:

```
=SWITCH(O18,"Ksh",P18,"USD",P18*U18,"")
```

You'd need Excel 2019 or 365 for the [`SWITCH()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) function to be available though.

Comment: oh wow THANK you! Fun!  Good to also have the "non-365" version please 

Comment: @BarbaraNapoliSehmi, the other answers have covered that.